# database design of subsets inside subsets in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a description of a Skeletal Muscle System, However I do not know the best approach as this system has several subsets wich happen to have subsets like:

## Skeletal Muscle System

- Position Of The Animal In Station
- Assessment Of Progress
- Valuation Of Trot
- Probing

  - Tip Thoracic

    - Region Escapolohumeral
    - Elbow And Forearm
    - Carpo And Fingers
  - Pelvic Limb

    - Pelvis
    - Knee
    - Hock
  - Specific Tests

    - Drawer Test
    - Test Ortolani
    - Other

Then I have a patient table

## Patient

- ID
- Name
- L_Name

Then I have a table that contains all systems (Skeletal Muscle System is part of that)

## Systems

- Skeletal Muscle System
- Nervous System
- Urinary System
- Respiratory

So I am doing something like

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_systems`; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_systems` (
 id_system INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name_system VARCHAR(25)    
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
INSERT INTO `tbl_systems` VALUES (1,'Skeletal_Muscle');
INSERT INTO `tbl_systems` VALUES (2,'Nervous');
INSERT INTO `tbl_systems` VALUES (3,'Urinary');
INSERT INTO `tbl_systems` VALUES (4,'Respiratory');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_patient`; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_patient` (
 id_patient INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name_patient VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "not available",
 l_name_patient VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "not available"
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `tbl_patient` VALUES (1,'Joe', 'Doe');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_systems_patient`; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_systems_patient` (
 id_patient_system INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 id_system INTEGER NOT NULL,
 id_patient INTEGER NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (id_system) REFERENCES `tbl_systems` (id_system),
 FOREIGN KEY (id_patient) REFERENCES `tbl_patient` (id_patient)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `tbl_systems_patient` VALUES (1,1,1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_Skeletal_Muscle`; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_Skeletal_Muscle` (
 id_system INTEGER NOT NULL,
 Position_In_Station VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "not available",
 Assessment_Of_Progress VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "not available",
 Valuation_Of_Trot VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "not available", 
 Probing VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "not available"
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
INSERT INTO `tbl_Skeletal_Muscle` 
 VALUES (1,'Normal','no progress','no change','failed');
```

- How to link the `tbl_Skeletal_Muscle` with a patient (`id_patient`) and get the the corresponding results, navigating through those tables?
- Is the approach correct or are there better options?
- How to add the missing data of `tbl_Skeletal_Muscle`? Do I create other tables? How many?

please take a look at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/751ae)

Comment: This  looks like a candidate for [The Nested Set Model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you are trying to mix patient-related information with information, which describes your system.

Let's for now assume that the hierarchy in skeletal muscle system is not terribly relevant to your database, but more a presentation issue. Likewise for the other systems.

Then you could create a table for each system, each table having a foreign key to a patient and containing *all* required columns, irrespective of the hierarchy. In that case the `Systems` information would be contained in the table layout itself and adding another system would require adding another table. A Systems table would not be needed at all. At first glance it indeed looks like `Systems` should become part of the design, because very few patients will differ in their Systems ;-)

If you want the hierarchy of skeletal muscle system to be expressed in that table you *could* add a parent column, where e.g. `Tip Thoracic`'s parent would be `Probing`. Still I believe this is a bad idea, because this parent relationship would be the same for all patients and thus does not convey any patient-related information.

You can add a Table which contains the hierarchy of systems to their components (Position Of The Animal In Station, ...). This table is then more like a configuration table, which describes your system (and not patients). You can however just as well capture this hierarchy in your application code or another configuration file.